# jQuery only tick 2 checkboxes in group of 4 checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I achieve in jQuery where the user can only select up to 2 checkboxes from group of 4 checkboxes? the user can select any as long as it is limited to 2 checkboxes

this is my code

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/4xcbye6z/>
```

Comment: There is only HTML in the fiddle. Did you try anything already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not post your fiddle correctly, at any rate, here is a modified version of your fiddle that does exactly what you want.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(e) {
    var c = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
    if (c.length == 3) {
      return false;
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <div class="tbl-info">
            <input type="checkbox" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <div class="tbl-info">
            <input type="checkbox" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <div class="tbl-info">
            <input type="checkbox" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <div class="tbl-info">
            <input type="checkbox" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dh7evp9s/

The idea is to capture the click event on the checkbox, and if there are already two checked ones to return a false in the event thus disallowing it.

Comment: your code is correct, but is there anyway where we can make it more "user friendly"? as of now the user needs to uncheck 1 of the 2 checkboxes to change the selection. is it possible to just have it like the 2nd selection will be unselected when the user selects another checkbox?

Comment: you can easily uncheck a random one by replacing the return false with something like ($("input[type=checkbox]:checked")[0]).prop('checked',false); however, unchecking the most recently checked box is a different story where you will need to start tracking the order of checks.

Answer (score 0):

Could find any code in your link, but this one checks all the marks :)

```
var countChecked = function(e) {
   var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
   if (n > 2) e.preventDefault();
};

$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
```

Also, see the excample from jQuery documentation: [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

And see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xcbye6z/2/)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Good point, this should do it...